# Words showing differently in the browsers

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am working on a site which has some Norwegian words. When I used "På" inside a `<span>` it is showing as "PÃ¥" in the browser.This is happening only for a particular page. For others it is working fine.I have tried to copy-paste from other working pages.But had no effect.It is showing "PÃ¥" instead of "På".Why this is happening?

Comment: Check <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> for your html page

Comment: That's indeed a charset problem. Also, the encoding of the specific file could be different than the other files, you might wanna save it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `&aring` insead of `å`

see this link for html codes-
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: First, it's `&aring;`, not `&aelig;`. Second, it's a real hell to type  the text with the HTML codes.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your special characters to equivalent HTML entities using this [converter](http://www.coach-tech.com/entityconverter.html)

Answer (score 1):

The character encoding of the page is wrong: the real encoding differs from the declared encoding. Using entity references for *all* non-Ascii characters would hide the symptoms (with the pertaining risk that later on, when someone inserts an “å”, things go wrong again). But the *solution* is to remove the conflict.

Check out the tutorial [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations). If you need further help with this, posting the URL (not just copy of all code) is essential.